# Can someone double check my resistor identification?

Tags: resistors

I have a resistor I need to replace.  It is fairly large measuring 11mm long with 4mm diameter.  All of the hobby resistors I have are 1/4 watt and make this thing look gigantic.

Do you think it is a 1 watt, or is there some larger value it could be?

I am also attempting to read the bands, and I see: Red Red Silver Gold.  Which is a 0.22 Ohms 5%.  Am I reading this correctly?

[image: Resistor in question - .22ohm 1W?]

I was actually able to find the schematic for this power supply, and it is a .22 Ohm.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Yep, its a resistor :)

Comment: Adding some information about what the resistor does (I.e. reverse engineered schematic) might help to see if the values make sense. Why do you think you need to replace it? Does it measure open?

Comment: it's from a power supply.  I will update my post to show the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 0.22 ohm sounds right - it's hard to tell from the pic if the silver band is actually a blue one (glare), but my guess is you have it correct.
2. Based on your size measurements, it could be either a half-watt or a one-watt.  There are 2-watt and larger resistors but I don't think that's what you have.

Comment: I'm sure it's not blue.  It could be gray, but it seems that is a VERY large value.  I couldn't even find any for sale.

Comment: @beachhouse - If you are saying large value after measuring using a DMM, then there is a possibility that the resistor got burnt but didn't open fully and hence giving you a very high resistance value.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear.  I'm saying that if the color had been gray, and not silver as I though.  The resistor value would be 2.2G Ohms

Comment: @beachhouse a gohm resistor would not need to be so high wattage